# Parse this month only

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am new to parse and I need help retrieve objects that are in the current month.
First I have a class called `food` and have a column of type `Date` called `food_date`

I am assuming I have to use greaterThan and less Than, but I am unsure how to.

```
NSDate *thisMonth = [NSDate date];
PFQuery *foodList = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"food"];
[foodList whereKey:@"food_date"
```

Comment: Show how you tried. What error did you get? What dates did you use? You are correct about the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.day = 1;

// Get the date of the first day of the current month
NSDate *minimumDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

components.month = components.month + 1;

// Get the date of the first day of the next month
NSDate *maximumDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

PFQuery *foodList = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"food"];
[foodList whereKey:@"food_date" greaterThanOrEqualTo:minimumDate];
[foodList whereKey:@"food_date" lessThan:maximumDate];

[foodList findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d foods.", objects.count);

        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

I hope that help.